# How to get a download progress for GET and AFNetworking 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

Is it possible at all? I know that there is a method:

```
public func GET(URLString: String, parameters: AnyObject?, progress downloadProgress: ((NSProgress) -> Void)?, success: ((NSURLSessionDataTask, AnyObject?) -> Void)?, failure: ((NSURLSessionDataTask?, NSError) -> Void)?) -> NSURLSessionDataTask?
```

but `downloadProgress` block is not called at all. How can I achieve this in other way?

This is how I call the method on a subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager`:

```
GET("words", parameters: nil, progress: { progress in

    print("---------- \(progress)") //not called

    }, success: { sessionDataTask, response in
        completionBlock(error) //this is called
    }) { sessionDataTask, error in
        completionBlock(error)
}
```

Headers of the response:

> [Server: Apache, Connection: Keep-Alive, Content-Type: application/json, Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2016 12:34:00 GMT, Content-Encoding: gzip, Keep-Alive: timeout=1, max=100, Content-Length: 5663, Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent]